# combine three object in new object

Tags: c#, api, web

i have three  objects i need to take from database  and combine all three to one list object when an if statement take place what i have for now is a code return only one object

```
 List<ITEMS1> ITEM1 = db.ITEMS1.ToList();
 ITEMS2 ITEM2 = db.ITEMS2;
 ITEMS3 ITEM3 = db.ITEMS3;
 ITM_Table itm_tab = new ITM_Table();
 foreach (var item in ITEMS1)
            {  if (ITEMS1.CODE== 999)
                {
                    itm_tab.ITEM_CODE = ITEMS1.ITEM_CODE;
                    itm_tab.ITEM_NAME = ITEMS1.ITEM_NAME;
                    itm_tab.ITEM_BCODE = ITEMS1.ITEM_BCODE;
                    itm_tab.ITEM_CUSTNOW = ITEM2 .ITEM_CUSTNOW;
                    itm_tab.ITEM_BALANCE = ITEM2 .ITEM_BALANCE;
                    itm_tab.QTY_MIN = ITEM3 .QTY_MIN;
                    itm_tab.QTY_R = ITEM3 .QTY_R;
           }
 return itm_tab;
```

how i can combine every object in the list object with the two other objects and return new list object of the all objects
I want the return result to look like this

```
[
{"ITEM_CODE ":999,"ITEM_NAME ":"new store","ITEM_BCODE":"M00001","ITEM_CUSTNOW ":"first","ITEM_BALANCE":900.00,"QTY_MIN":100.0,"QTY_R":100.0},
{"ITEM_CODE ":999,"ITEM_NAME ":"new store2","ITEM_BCODE":"M00002","ITEM_CUSTNOW ":"second","ITEM_BALANCE":800.00,"QTY_MIN":30.0,"QTY_R":00.0},
{"ITEM_CODE ":999,"ITEM_NAME ":"new store3","ITEM_BCODE":"M00005","ITEM_CUSTNOW ":"th3","ITEM_BALANCE":40.00,"QTY_MIN":100.0,"QTY_R":100.0},
]
```

the value of  "ITEM_CUSTNOW "&"QTY_MIN "&"QTY_MIN "&"QTY_R " should Depends on the value of "ITEM_NAME "

Comment: You could create an interface and have each class derive from that interface and then use `List<interfaceName>`. Or create a `List<Object>` and store each item into that `List<object>`, but then you could not easily access specific properties from each object.

Comment: pleas can you give me small example

Comment: I didn't understand. You're trying to combine every object that has the same `CODE` into a 4th object that has all the previous 3 objects properties?

Comment: Yes, exactly and I want to return a list of the new objects that have the three previous objects

Comment: What does "have the three previous objects" mean in programming terms? What do you expect the C# type (class) to look like for the answer?

Comment: I update my question @NetMage@Magnetron